# Rep has wrong background color on MSO

Tags: bug, profile-page, meta

I noticed the background color behind my reputation is off on MSO

[image]

When compared to my profile on SO
[image]

Comment: Same here (Win 10, Firefox 63.0.3, both 64 bit)

Comment: @DavyM, that was a typo. It should be MSO.

Comment: Sites have their own color scheme, there is no expectation that they should look the same.  De-emphasizing rep on MSO is not exactly inappropriate.

Comment: It seems like a lot of other styling is also very different between sites and the meta counterpart.  Different font sizes, fore-and back- ground colors, lack of reputation graph.  Probably intentional?

Comment: @HansPassant, I don't ask them to be the exact same. But seeing this large square around the rep number clearly makes for poor UX, especially as it almost overlaps with the "top XX sentence". As I have hopes that SO devs are capable of design to some extent I believe this to be a bug.

Comment: @ryanyuyu I agree, however this looks to ugly to be intentional if you ask me.

Comment: Do consider editing your question to point out that it is not about the color but that you're not happy with layout.  Mentioning the browser is always a good idea as well when layout is the issue.